# Inno Setup Unknown identifier - is this perhaps a syntax error

Tags: inno-setup

I have not been using Inno Setup for some years, but now I needed to rerun an .iss file from 2014. It used to work, but now I get `Unknown identifier`on this line:

```
[Setup]
AppName=errw32
AppVerName=errw32 (ver 0.58)
DefaultDirName={pf}\errw32

[Code]

{ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// Messages etc }

function myassert(bTrue : boolean ; sMsg : string ): boolean;
begin
end; { myassert }

function err_dir_Known(): string;
begin
end; { err_dir_Known }

function Check_err_dir_Ok()                           : boolean;
begin
   if not myassert(length(err_dir_Known()) > 0, 'err_dir unknown in Check_err_dir_Ok')
      then exit;
end; { Check_err_dir_Ok }
```

The error message is:

```
Line 21:
Column 11:
Unknown identifier 'myassert'
```

Note that the function `myassert` is defined above this error in the script file.

Is this perhaps a syntax error now (in `Pascal`)? Or what is wrong?

---

EDIT: Included a complete example that fails.

Comment: Nothin wrong about that line, if `my_dir_Known` is also defined. Show us [mcve].

Comment: Ah, thanks. Inno is complaining about myassert, but it could be the other function.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks. I tracked it down, see the example above and my "answer". However now I wonder if there is anything wrong with the comment in the code or if this is a compiler error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Martin Prikryl who told me there was no error on the line Inno complained about. Tracking it down I found it was the comment that screwed the compiler up:

```
{ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// Messages etc }
```

But now I wonder if there is anything wrong with this comment?

---

EDIT Yes, I guess the two comment styles clashes here, see https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse2.html